Find difference in Rotation about a specific sequence of rotation
I have two Quaternion rotations
Quaternion rotation1 = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardVector1, upVector1);
Quaternion rotation2 = Quaternion.LookRotation(forwardVector2, upVector2);

I want to calculate the difference between these two rotation about a specific sequence of rotation.
The way I calculate now is like this:
Quaternion difference = Quaternion.Inverse(rotation2) * rotation1;

How can I calculate difference with the following conditions?

If rotation2 was first rotated along X axis, then Y and then Z.
If rotation2 was first rotated along Y axis, then Z and X. etc.

Basically I need to get six possible differences (xyz, xzy, yxz, yzx, zxy and zyx)
Any help/suggestions on this would be great!

If sounds like you want to convert this into euler angles, or more specifically, Tait–Bryan angles, and take the difference there.

What is the difference between 1. and 2. condition. If the end result is the same and you only have that, you can't differentiate them. Either way if you use something like Quaternion.RotateTowards your rotation is not sequential all axis are moved at the same time with the shortest way towards the new rotation point

Convert rotation2  to corresponding Euler Angles? Or look at swing twist decomposition.
